# How to resize partition of a micro SD card. 32GB to 8GB card

Tags: sd-card, filesystem

I am currently using a 32GB micro SD card for testing. Now I want to save the image however, there is a lot of unused space. I was hoping how can I reformat the image to fit nicely into a single partition with only ~<8GB of data so I can flash it to a 8GB SD in the future.

The way I have it setup at the moment is I have flashed a backup of the SD card but is using a 32GB file system. I want to in the future use smaller sized cards.

Was hoping if someone could help me with the setup.

I am currently using OSX as my main computer. Checking out the Disk Util (GUI) it didn't seem I could do that.

edit:
I am using `dd` to flash my images on OSX.

[image: RPI storage]

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the SD Card in a Linux machine (or other which can manipulate `ext4` partitions) to resize the partitions.

You cannot do this on `OS X`, although it was possible on earlier `OS X` with external software.

Probably the easiest way to do this is in a SD Card reader on the Pi itself.

You could then use `dd` to image the active part of the SD Card, as in the duplicate link.

The best solution however would be to use the SD Copier which is in the latest Raspbian (4.4.9 kernel) to copy to a 8GB SD Card.